# How can I import the following function in another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux-persist

As we know anonymous function (arrow function) can be exported as default from a file, my question is how can I import this in another file

**If I export the following function that returns an Object, then how can I use the returned store / returned persistor in another function**

```
export default () => {
    let store = createStore(persistedReducer, compose(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()));
    let persistor = persistStore(store);
    return { store, persistor };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use default import:

```js
import storageCreator from './file';
```

Comment: Actually I want to know that how can I get only the 'persistor'

Answer (score 0):

let the file name is index.js

```
import xyz from './index';
```

Comment: How to get only the 'persistor'. If I import xyz you mentioned I get the exported function, but I need one of the returned value not the whole

Answer (score 0):

```
// File A
export default () => {}

// File B
import myFunction from './fileA';
const sameFunction = require('./fileA');

// File A
export const myFunction = () => {}

// File B
import { myFunction } from './fileA';
const fileAExports = require('./fileA');
const { myFunction } = fileAExports;
```

More info here https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

You can't return like this. If you are using store concept you can use like this.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

and

```
import store from "./store";
import PrivateRoute from "./helper/privateRoutes";
import { loadUser } from "./store/actions/userActions";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ToastContainer />
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/posts" component={Post} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/addpost" component={AddPost} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/todos" component={Todo} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/addtodo" component={AddTodo} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: "You can't return like this" --- Please see this link, they used like this in 'Basic Usage' section